# selecting the first and the last row of partition orderd by date

Tags: sql, pivot, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

hi u have a data set that looks like this 
[image]

i need to write a query to return the first and last color that each person selected.
this is my code

```
    Select t1.name,t1.color,min(t1.rnkmin) ,t2.color,max(t2.rnkmax) 
    From(
   Select name,color,
  Danse_rank() over(partition by name order by time asc) as rnkmin 
  From table 3) as t1 inner join (
 Select name,color,
 Danse_rank() over (partition by name order by date asc) as rnkmax 
  From table 3) as t2 on t1.name=t2.name
```

but sadly i get an error and i dont understand why 
thank you for the help :)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()` twice:

```
select color, name, time
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by name order by time) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(partition by name order by time desc) rn_desc
    from mytable t
) t
where rn_asc = 1 or rn_desc = 1
```

If you want both colors in the same record, then you can aggregate:

```
select 
    name, 
    max(case when rn_asc = 1 then color end) as first_color
    max(case when rn_desc = 1 then color end) as last_color
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by name order by time) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(partition by name order by time desc) rn_desc
    from mytable t
) t
where rn_asc = 1 or rn_desc = 1
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

In many databases, the fastest method will use correlated subqueries:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.time = (select min(t2.time)
                from t t2
                where t2.name = t.name
               ) or
      t.time = (select max(t2.time)
                from t t2
                where t2.name = t.name 
               ) ;
```

You want an index on `(name, time)`.